# Strange format length in struct

Tags: python, struct

I was playing around to unpack a jpeg image, and I stumbled upon a very interesting behavior.

A H format seemed like it was 3 bytes long. I have managed to isolate this format string:

```
print(calcsize('15s2s')) #prints 17
print(calcsize('15sH')) #prints 18
```

The docs say that the H unpacks 2 bytes to an integer.

Oddly enough when I change it to this they both return 16:

```
print(calcsize('14s2s')) #prints 16
print(calcsize('14sH')) #prints 16
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the top of the `struct` module documentation:

> **Note**: By default, the result of packing a given C struct **includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment** for the C types involved; similarly, alignment is taken into account when unpacking. This behavior is chosen so that the bytes of a packed struct correspond exactly to the layout in memory of the corresponding C struct. To handle platform-independent data formats or omit implicit pad bytes, use standard size and alignment instead of native size and alignment: see [*Byte Order, Size, and Alignment*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct-alignment) for details.

Emphasis mine. You are seeing the effect of alignment padding here.

Set a byte order or use `=` to produce a non-padded format:

```
>>> from struct import calcsize
>>> calcsize('15sH')
18
>>> calcsize('=15sH')
17
```

Comment: Yes, the quoted text I included has that link. :-)

Comment: Oh, nvm, didn't see the link (bug in mobile stylesheet? It doesn't differ from static text for me).